# Signature to Image not saving signature. Thomas bradley sigPad

Tags: php, html, html5-canvas, png, signature

Alright so I have the signature pad running and it works. It also creates the signature.png in my working directory just fine.However, The png is blank and its not saving the signature.

All of the files are listed below.

This first one is the form.

```
 <html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Full-Window · Signature Pad</title>
  <style>
    * {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    html, body {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    html, body, form {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    html, form {
        padding: 0px;
    }
    html, body, fieldset {
        background: #aaa;
    }
    fieldset {
        position: absolute;
        border: 5px solid #aaa;
        background: #aaa;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
    canvas {
        outline: 5px solid #aaa;
        background: #fff;
    }
    input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
        font-size: larger;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/jquery.signaturepad.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../assets/flashcanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="finaladd.php" class="sigPad">

  <div class="sig sigWrapper">
    <div class="typed"></div>
    <canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
    <fieldset>
            <input type="reset" value="clear" />
            <input type='submit' value='submit'/>
        </fieldset>
  </div>

</form>



  <script src="assets/numeric-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/bezier.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.signaturepad.js"></script>
  <script>
  (function(window) {
    var $canvas,
        onResize = function(event) {
          $canvas.attr({
            height: window.innerHeight,
            width: window.innerWidth
          });
        };

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $canvas = $('canvas');
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', onResize, false);
      window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
      onResize();

      $('form').signaturePad({
        drawBezierCurves: true,
        variableStrokeWidth:true,
        drawOnly: true,
        defaultAction: 'drawIt',
        validateFields: false,
        lineWidth: 0,
        output: null,
        sigNav: null,
        name: null,
        submit: 'input[type=submit]',
        typed: null,
        clear: 'input[type=reset]',
        typeIt: null,
        drawIt: null,
        typeItDesc: null,
        drawItDesc: null
      });
    });
  }(this));
  </script>
  <script src="assets/json2.min.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

this next one is where the form post too and saved to signature.png

```
<?php
require_once 'signature-to-image.php';

$json = $_POST['output']; // From Signature Pad
$img = sigJsonToImage($json);

imagepng($img, 'signature.png');
imagedestroy($img);
// Destroy the image in memory when complete
```

and this last one is the signature-to-image.php file that it requires.

```
<?php
/**
 *  Signature to Image: A supplemental script for Signature Pad that
 *  generates an image of the signature’s JSON output server-side using PHP.
 *
 *  @project ca.thomasjbradley.applications.signaturetoimage
 *  @author Thomas J Bradley <hey@thomasjbradley.ca>
 *  @link http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-to-image
 *  @link http://github.com/thomasjbradley/signature-to-image
 *  @copyright Copyright MMXI–, Thomas J Bradley
 *  @license New BSD License
 *  @version 1.1.0
 */
/**
 *  Accepts a signature created by signature pad in Json format
 *  Converts it to an image resource
 *  The image resource can then be changed into png, jpg whatever PHP GD supports
 *
 *  To create a nicely anti-aliased graphic the signature is drawn 12 times it's original size then shrunken
 *
 *  @param string|array $json
 *  @param array $options OPTIONAL; the options for image creation
 *    imageSize => array(width, height)
 *    bgColour => array(red, green, blue) | transparent
 *    penWidth => int
 *    penColour => array(red, green, blue)
 *    drawMultiplier => int
 *
 *  @return object
 */
function sigJsonToImage ($json, $options = array()) {
  $defaultOptions = array(
    'imageSize' => array(198, 55)
    ,'bgColour' => array(0xff, 0xff, 0xff)
    ,'penWidth' => 2
    ,'penColour' => array(0x14, 0x53, 0x94)
    ,'drawMultiplier'=> 12
  );
  $options = array_merge($defaultOptions, $options);
  $img = imagecreatetruecolor($options['imageSize'][0] * $options['drawMultiplier'], $options['imageSize'][1] * $options['drawMultiplier']);
  if ($options['bgColour'] == 'transparent') {
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    $bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
  } else {
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($img, $options['bgColour'][0], $options['bgColour'][1], $options['bgColour'][2]);
  }
  $pen = imagecolorallocate($img, $options['penColour'][0], $options['penColour'][1], $options['penColour'][2]);
  imagefill($img, 0, 0, $bg);
  if (is_string($json))
    $json = json_decode(stripslashes($json));
  foreach ($json as $v)
    drawThickLine($img, $v->lx * $options['drawMultiplier'], $v->ly * $options['drawMultiplier'], $v->mx * $options['drawMultiplier'], $v->my * $options['drawMultiplier'], $pen, $options['penWidth'] * ($options['drawMultiplier'] / 2));
  $imgDest = imagecreatetruecolor($options['imageSize'][0], $options['imageSize'][1]);
  if ($options['bgColour'] == 'transparent') {
    imagealphablending($imgDest, false);
    imagesavealpha($imgDest, true);
  }
  imagecopyresampled($imgDest, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $options['imageSize'][0], $options['imageSize'][0], $options['imageSize'][0] * $options['drawMultiplier'], $options['imageSize'][0] * $options['drawMultiplier']);
  imagedestroy($img);
  return $imgDest;
}
/**
 *  Draws a thick line
 *  Changing the thickness of a line using imagesetthickness doesn't produce as nice of result
 *
 *  @param object $img
 *  @param int $startX
 *  @param int $startY
 *  @param int $endX
 *  @param int $endY
 *  @param object $colour
 *  @param int $thickness
 *
 *  @return void
 */
function drawThickLine ($img, $startX, $startY, $endX, $endY, $colour, $thickness) {
  $angle = (atan2(($startY - $endY), ($endX - $startX)));
  $dist_x = $thickness * (sin($angle));
  $dist_y = $thickness * (cos($angle));
  $p1x = ceil(($startX + $dist_x));
  $p1y = ceil(($startY + $dist_y));
  $p2x = ceil(($endX + $dist_x));
  $p2y = ceil(($endY + $dist_y));
  $p3x = ceil(($endX - $dist_x));
  $p3y = ceil(($endY - $dist_y));
  $p4x = ceil(($startX - $dist_x));
  $p4y = ceil(($startY - $dist_y));
  $array = array(0=>$p1x, $p1y, $p2x, $p2y, $p3x, $p3y, $p4x, $p4y);
  imagefilledpolygon($img, $array, (count($array)/2), $colour);
}
```

If someone could please help me. I have been trying for days now to get this to work with no success.

the error that I keep getting is.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\CareMed\signature-to-image.php on line 51
```

I also did this dump below

```
$json = $_POST['output'];
var_dump($json, json_decode(stripslashes($json)));
```

Comment: `stripslashes()` is likely corrupting your json. it's **NOT** aware of json syntax and will remove ALL slashes in the text, regardless of whether they required by json or not. e.g. `"Foo \" Bar"` is valid json, but after strippping it'll be `"Foo " Bar"` and be corrupt.

Comment: Are you talking about the striplashes in the above dump? If so, I can remove that dump and I still get the forreach error. I only add that var_dump to view that it was indeed outputing the json. The forreach error is whats stopping it though.

Comment: are you talking about $json = json_decode(stripslashes($json)); in the signature-to-png.php file? If so how can i change that?

Comment: `$decoded = json_decode($json)`. and since your vardump shows a proper array structure, it's not stripslashes (in this particular case). you need to figure out why `$json` becomes a not-array when it reaches `foreach()`.

Comment: So on this particulary version. It was a full-window mode. On this version it only had a CLEAR button to erase the current signature on the screen. It did NOT have a submit button. I added everything on the form that you see that says submit. Did I do something incorrect there? I read that json defaults the output name of the signature to output so yea. Can you see anything why it would not becoming an array?  I am using this https://github.com/ezl/signature-pad if you click that link then go into the folder named examples. You will see one labeled full-window.html

Comment: There was no submit button on that so I added my own. If I just set up the normal sized example of this signature pad where it is only a tiny spot to sign on the screen it submits and saves the image in the .png just fine. Why would it not work with this version? There has to be a obvious solution to this. Im sure I am overlooking something simple but I have been trying to do this for days now so I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I could not fit the rest into the body as I exceeded the body limit.

When i did the dump, this is what I got.

```
 string(6330) "[{"lx":369,"ly":534,"mx":369,"my":533},
    {"lx":370,"ly":539,"mx":369,"my":534},
    {"lx":368,"ly":547,"mx":370,"my":539},
    [...snip...]
    {"lx":1253,"ly":559,"mx":1251,"my":554},
    {"lx":1262,"ly":562,"mx":1253,"my":559},
    {"lx":1271,"ly":563,"mx":1262,"my":562},
    {"lx":1279,"ly":563,"mx":1271,"my":563}]"


array(164) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (4) { ["lx"]=> int(369) ["ly"]=> int(534) ["mx"]=> int(369) ["my"]=> int(533) }
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (4) { ["lx"]=> int(370) ["ly"]=> int(539) ["mx"]=> int(369) ["my"]=> int(534) }
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["lx"]=> int(368) ["ly"]=> int(547) ["mx"]=> int(370) ["my"]=> int(539) } 
[...snip...]
    [160]=> object(stdClass)#161 (4) { ["lx"]=> int(1253) ["ly"]=> int(559) ["mx"]=> int(1251) ["my"]=> int(554) }
    [161]=> object(stdClass)#162 (4) { ["lx"]=> int(1262) ["ly"]=> int(562) ["mx"]=> int(1253) ["my"]=> int(559) }
    [162]=> object(stdClass)#163 (4) { ["lx"]=> int(1271) ["ly"]=> int(563) ["mx"]=> int(1262) ["my"]=> int(562) }
    [163]=> object(stdClass)#164 (4) { ["lx"]=> int(1279) ["ly"]=> int(563) ["mx"]=> int(1271) ["my"]=> int(563) }
}
```

which tells me that it obviously is outputting the signature.

Comment: since most of that is just repeated garbage, you could slice out the middle 90% and put in a `[..snip..]` type thing.